# Css overlap horizontal menus

Tags: css

I am using two menus and one floating right while other floating left. Both of them using percentages for size issues but when I try to minimize my browser left and right menu overlaps. I just want both to minimize acording to those percentage values. Or just dont want my navigation menu to be overlapped by right gridview menu

Both sharing two pictures to make problem more understandable

Left menu

```
<div id="sol" class="sola">
```

Left menu related css code

```
.sola {float:left;display:inline;}
#sol {width:15%;}
```

Right menu

```
 <div id="orta" class="saga">
```

Right menu related css code

```
.orta {text-align:center;}
.saga {float:right;display:inline;}
```

Left and right before minimizing browser
http://g1206.hizliresim.com/y/h/7yxdg.jpg

Left and right after minimizing browser
http://g1206.hizliresim.com/y/h/7yxks.jpg

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and use tags properly, not mindlessly fill them in.

Comment: btw, you have a .orta but also id="orta".